# is there a difference between using NetworkManager.conf and using nmcli

Tags: networking, network-manager, nmcli

1. In NetworkManager.conf, I can specify

   ```
   [keyfile]
   unmanaged-devices=interface-name:vboxnet0
   ```
2. I can also use nmcli as follows

   ```
   nmcli device set vboxnet0 managed no
   ```
3. is there a difference between these two approaches. Especially, on 2. does it work after every reboot?

Comment: Related: [How do I make persistent changes with nmcli in non interactive mode?](https://superuser.com/q/1404124/61370)

Answer (score 0):

The two do the same thing. The 2nd is to test if it works before using 1. to commit it so is not permanent (and will revert back to what is in `NetworkManager.conf` after a reboot).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there a programmatical way to edit NetworkManager.conf (I mean to use a command rather than to edit file programmatically)?

Answer (score 0):

both make a device unmanaged, but it's not exactly the same.

NetworkManager by default likes to manage devices, so there are several ways to make it unmanaged. These are only two of them. There are also

- udev-rules (`ENV{NM_UNMANAGED}="1"`)
- `[device*].managed=0` in NetworkManager.conf
- `NM_CONTROLLED=no` in ifcfg files

---

- `nmcli device set $IFNAME managed $OPTION` basically makes a D-Bus call. That means:

  - it can be done by a non-root user (if policykit permits)
  - it can be changed at runtime
- `[keyfile].unmanaged-devices` instead

  - requires root permissions
  - only takes effect after reloading the configuration with `systemctl reload NetworkManager` or `killall -HUP NetworkManager`.

---

Also relevant is, that as there are multiple ways to make a device unmanaged, which method wins?

- as explained in `man NetworkManager.conf`, `[keyfile].unmanaged-devices` (and ifcfg's `NM_CONTROLLED=no`) always renders a device unmanaged. You cannot override it via other means.
- on the other hand, the UDEV-rule and `[device*].managed` can be overrule via D-Bus. So if you set

```
   [device-my-unmanaged]
   match-device=eth0
   managed=0
```

and then `nmcli device set eth0 managed yes` will still work.

---

Finally if you change it via D-Bus (nmcli), then it also gets remembered in `/run/NetworkManager/devices/` state files. That means, it will survive service restart but won't survive reboot.

---

> Is there a programmatical way to edit NetworkManager.conf (I mean to use a command rather than to edit file programmatically)

Well, there is `sed` :)

Actually, I find it easier to drop configuration snippets to `/{usr/lib,etc,run}/NetworkManager/conf.d`, then you don't need to edit files. You drop/delete your snippet and if you leave a comment in the snippet, it can be clear who created it. Read `man NetworkManager.conf` about the order in which conf.d files are merged.

Comment: to be clear, setting it via D-Bus does not survive reboot!

Comment: thank you, thaller!